# moving window regression between two tif image/2D numpy array/xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, regression, tiff, python-xarray

I have two TIFF time series ( say temperature and precipitation), and I'm interested in performing moving window regression between these two rasters for each day. My goal is to export the slope, intercept, and predicted values. I have written Python code for this task, but it's currently running quite slowly, especially when processing raster with dimensions of 4000x4000.

I'm searching for a tailored approach to reduce the computational time for this task. Here is my code

```
def linear_regression(temperature, precipitation):
    X = temperature.flatten()
    y = precipitation.flatten()  

    # Remove rows with NaN values
    valid_rows = ~np.isnan(y)
    X = X[valid_rows]
    y = y[valid_rows]

   if len(X) < 2:
      intercept, coefficients = np.nan, np.nan
   else:
      # Add a constant (intercept) to the X matrix
      X = sm.add_constant(X)
    
      # Fit the multiple linear regression model
      model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

      # Extract slope coefficients and intercept
      intercept = model.params[0]
      coefficients = model.params[1:]
    
      return intercept, coefficients 


def moving_window_regression(a_T, a_P, window_size):
    pad_width = window_size // 2
    
    padded_T = np.pad(a_T, pad_width, mode='symmetric')
    padded_P = np.pad(a_P, pad_width, mode='symmetric') 
    
    rows, cols = padded_P.shape
    result_slope= np.empty_like(padded_P)
    result_intercept = np.empty_like(padded_P)
    

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            w_T = padded_T[i:i + window_size, j:j + window_size]        
            w_P = padded_P[i:i + window_size, j:j + window_size] 
            
            # Call the function to get intercept and coefficients
            intercept, coefficients = linear_regression(w_T, w_P)
            
            result_slope[i, j] = coefficients[0]
            result_intercept[i, j] = intercept
    
    return result_slope,result_intercept

original_array1 = np.random.rand(100,100)
original_array2 = np.random.rand(100,100)#Replace this with your actual data
original_array2[45:65, 45:65] =np.nan
original_array2[5:20,5:50]=np.nan

result_slope,result_intercept = moving_window_regression(original_array1, original_array2,50)
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't work, raises ```TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable``` on line 48 ```result_slope[i, j] = coefficients[0]```